# Pascal Calendar

Tags: calendar, pascal

I want to make a full year of calendar, but this code only show calendar with the given first day and month day length. How can i do with this code? Any suggest? No array allowed.

Here my code output :

[image]

```pascal
Program Contoh81;
uses crt;
type 
    Hari1pekan = (Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat);
    haribulan = 1 .. 31;

var 
    i, awalbulan : hari1pekan;
    j, tglmaks : haribulan;
    x, y, k, lebar : integer;

begin
    clrscr;
    write('Hari pertama awal bulan: ');
    readln(awalbulan);
    write('Jumlah hari bulan ini: ');
    readln(tglmaks);
    writeln;
    
    lebar := 7;

    for i := sun to sat do
        write(i : lebar);
    
    y := 5;
    x := ord(awalbulan);

    for j := 1 to tglmaks do
    begin
        if x = 7 then
        begin 
            x := 0;
            y := y + 1;
        end;

        gotoxy(lebar * x + 1, y);
        write(j : 3);
        x := x + 1;
    end;

    readln
end.
```

Comment: well obviously if your last day of the month is Wednesday, the first of the next month is a thursday

Comment: You need to write a function which returns the number of days in February for a given year number depending on whether or not it is a leap year.  Apart from that the code necessary is pretty trivial.4

Answer (score 1):

finnaly i got this so far :). But there's one more problem that make my code flashing. like instead of printing :

```
January 2021
sun mon tue wed thu fri sat




February 2021 
sun mon tue wed thu fri sat
.
.
.
.
.

etc
```

but my code print like january and then clear screen, and print february clear screen and so on.

With the help from @TomBrunberg, i finally fixed all of the problems that occur. Here my final code.

```
program nomor_satu;
uses crt;
const Januari = 31;
Februari = 28;
Maret = 31;
April = 30;
Mei = 31;
Juni = 30;
Juli = 31;
Agustus = 31;
September = 30;
Oktober = 31;
Nopember = 30;
Desember = 31;
kabisat = 366 mod 7;
Normal = 365 mod 7;

type Blntype = record
jumlah : Byte;
NamaBln : String;
end;

var DataBln : array[1..12] of Blntype;
HariPertama, totalHari,
NumDays : word;
s:string;

var Bln,Thn:word;
    v:Integer;

procedure GetDataBln;
begin
        DataBln[1].jumlah:=31;
        DataBln[1].NamaBln:='Januari';
        DataBln[2].jumlah:=28;
        DataBln[2].NamaBln:='Februari';
        DataBln[3].jumlah:=31;
        DataBln[3].NamaBln:='Maret';
        DataBln[4].jumlah:=30;
        DataBln[4].NamaBln:='April';
        DataBln[5].jumlah:=31;
        DataBln[5].NamaBln:='Mei';
        DataBln[6].jumlah:=30;
        DataBln[6].NamaBln:='Juni';
        DataBln[7].jumlah:=31;
        DataBln[7].NamaBln:='Juli';
        DataBln[8].jumlah:=31;
        DataBln[8].NamaBln:='Agustus';
        DataBln[9].jumlah:=30;
        DataBln[9].NamaBln:='September';
        DataBln[10].jumlah:=31;
        DataBln[10].NamaBln:='Oktober';
        DataBln[11].jumlah:=30;
        DataBln[11].NamaBln:='Nopember';
        DataBln[12].jumlah:=31;
        DataBln[12].NamaBln:='Desember';
end;

function ThnKabisat(n:Word):Boolean;
begin
    if (N mod 4 = 0) and (N mod 100 <> 0) or (N mod 400 = 0) then
    ThnKabisat:=True
    else ThnKabisat:=False;
end;


procedure perhitungan(Thn, Bln:word);
var i : Word;
begin
    NumDays := 1;
    for I := 1 to Thn - 1 do
    begin
        if ThnKabisat(I) then 
            Inc(NumDays, kabisat) 
        else 
            Inc(NumDays, Normal); 
    end;
    for I := 1 to Bln - 1 do
        Inc(NumDays, DataBln[I].jumlah);
    totalHari := DataBln[Bln].jumlah;
    if ThnKabisat(Thn) then
    begin
        if Bln > 2 then Inc(NumDays)
        else if Bln = 2 then
        Inc(totalHari, 1);
    end;
    
    HariPertama := NumDays Mod 7
end;

Procedure KalenderKeluaran(Thn, Bln:word);
Var
i,v : Byte;
tanya : char;

begin
    perhitungan(Thn, Bln);
    gotoxy(6,WhereY);writeLn('Bulan ',DataBln[Bln].NamaBln,' Tahun ',Thn);
    writeLn;
    writeLn('-----------------------------------');
    writeLn('Ahad  Sen  Sel  Rab  Kam  Jum  Sab ');
    writeLn('-----------------------------------');
    GotoXY(5*HariPertama+1,WhereY);
    for i := 1 to TotalHari do
    begin
        if i<10 then write('  ',i,'  ');
        if i>9 then write('  ',i,' ');
        if WhereX > 32 then writeLn;
    end;
    writeLn('  ');
end;


begin
        GetDataBln;
        writeln(' Masukkan Tahun Kalender : ');readln(Thn);
        for v:=1 to 12 do 
            KalenderKeluaran(Thn,v);
        writeLn;
        writeLn('  ');
        writeLn('-----------------------------------');
    end.
end.

begin
        GetDataBln;
        writeln(' Masukkan Tahun Kalender : ');readln(Thn);
        for v:=1 to 12 do 
            KalenderKeluaran(Thn,v);
        gotoxy(1,9);
        gotoxy(1,8);
        writeLn;
        writeLn('  ');
        writeLn('-----------------------------------');
    end.
end.
```

Comment: Btw, you have a `ClrScr;` in `KalenderKerluaran`. That seems to be the reason for the problem you mention. Btw(2) It is a pain to try to make sense of a foreign language. Stack Overflow has a requirement that the post and all material (incl. code) are in English on the English sites.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thank you for the answer and the `clrscr;` work for me. And I'm really sorry because this is my first time asking question at stackoverflow.

Comment: No problem, if the `clrscr` was the only remaining problem and you fix it in the code that you have posted as an answer, then it is indeed a valid answer, and you can leave it as it is.

Comment: You say: *How do I keep the output for whole year (Jan to Des)?* and I have already told you that the reason for not showing the whole year, is the `clrscr;` in `KalenderKeluaran`. In other words: remove the  `clrscr;` in `KalenderKeluaran`.

Comment: Further, you have other errors too, that messes up the display within `KalenderKeluaran()`:  In addition to already mentioned `clrscr`, there is a `GotoXY(6, 1)` to be modified to `GotoXY(6, WhereY)`. After writing the monthly header there is a `GotoXY(5 * HariPertama + 1, 5) which forces the day numbers to appear on line 5 of display. The "5" needs to be changed to `WhereY`. Finally you need to do something also to the two `GotoXY(1, 11);` and `GotoXY(1, 13);` just before  `write('Anda mau mencoba...`. Change them so the text is not written on the calendar.

Comment: Oh my god this really helpp, thank you so much for the well explanation answer @TomBrunberg